# LINQ DeleteOnSubmit: will deleted record be shown in next queries before submit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

I've have implemented a nested data set model to show a hierarchy in my database. So for deleting leaf nodes, after removing nodes, I will shift nodes left by 2. 

Implementing this idea in C# I developed this code:

```
    private void deleteSectionFromTable(section selectedSection)
    {
        int leftIndex = selectedSection.left_index;
        int rightIndex = selectedSection.right_index;
        dbContext.sections.DeleteOnSubmit(selectedSection);
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        var sectionWithLeftCondition = (from s in dbContext.sections
                                    where s.left_index > leftIndex
                                    select s);
        var sectionWithRightCondition = (from s in dbContext.sections
                                         where s.right_index > rightIndex
                                         select s);
        foreach (section s in sectionWithLeftCondition)
        {
            s.left_index -= 2;
        }
        foreach (section s in sectionWithRightCondition)
        {
            s.right_index -= 2;
        }
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

In my code, I used `dbContext.SubmitChanges()` instantly after `DeleteOnSubmit` since I'm not sure if in the next queries if deleted record will show up or not? 

**My Question:** I want to know if LINQ is smart enought to exclude node with `DeleteOnSubmit` status from query results or not.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, deleted objects will not be returned by subsequent queries on the same `Table` after you call `SubmitChanges`, but until you do they are still available for selection.

Basically as soon as `SubmitChanges` completes the data structures both on the SQL server and in the internal object tracking lists in the `DataContext` are updated to reflect the changes you have made, so subsequent queries should never return objects that you have deleted.

Which seems a little irrelevant here, since the queries you are running after the `SubmitChanges` call should never return the deleted item anyway.

Comment: I meant if the first `SubmitChanges` was not there, result was same?

Comment: Oh, that's different.  No, you have to submit or the record will be returned.

Comment: Could you please add this to your post? So I can choose it as write answer.